# elastic cluster dates folder space issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I have a three node elasticsearch cluster running in my environment. Now I have got a task to upgrade the elasticsearch to a newer latest version. while I'm doing preparation work on this upgrade activity I noticed that space occupied by 'data' folder occupied on three instances are different as mentioned below.

2 out of 3 instances has the 'data' folder occupied almost same.

on third node same 'data' folder is occupied with less space compared to other instances.

node1 - data folder is occupied with 4.5g

node2 - data folder is occupied with 390m

node3 - data folder is occupied with 4.6g

why is one instance has very less space occupied. what could be the possibility to have one data node occupied very less compared to other instances in the cluster. what should I check to get more clarity on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thats mostly due to your index configurations in your Elasticsearch cluster that doesn't spread data to your Elasticsearch data nodes evenly, you need to do below things to identify the cause.

1. List all the indices on your cluster and filter the bigger indices based on their total size using `_cat/indices?v` API and mostly your bigger indices  have PRIMARY SHARDS and REPLICA SHARDS assigned only to 2 nodes that have bigger size.
2. List all the indices or indices filtered from step 1, with their PRIMARY SHARDS and REPLICA SHARDS and their size using `_cat/shards?v` API, this will tell you which indices shards are allocated to which nodes and taking how much space on that node.

**Also check if your node that has small size is not a dedicated master node as shards are not allocated on the dedicated master nodes.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Amit, I will further check as you suggested and keep you informed if anything needed.

Comment: @RaviMitraReddy were u able to resolve issue?

Comment: I don't have necessary permissions to further check on this. I have requested for the permissions and will post here once I check this. Thanks for checking for an update @Amit.

Comment: @RaviMitraReddy did you finally manage to check it again, its been really long and would be great if you can provide update